# How to execute a gradle task from powershell script?

Tags: powershell, gradle

I'm loking for a command in powershell that executes a gradle task. I could not find as of now.

I tried below things:

```
& gradle main
Start-Process -FilePath "build.gradle" -ArgumentList gradle main
PowerShell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& 'build.gradle'"
```

Note: The task in build.gradle which i want to execute is **main**. Usually from cmd I just enter **gradle main**.

Could you please help me to find out how to execute gradle task from **.ps1** (powershell script) ?

Answer (score 0):

The below commands works:-

```
./gradlew main
```

Comment: You've changed the file name from `gradle` to `gradlew`, but it sounds like the issue was simply that the executable you're trying to run is located in the _current directory_, which in PowerShell requires invocation with an explicit path, such as `./` The linked duplicate has details.